# Stow Map One Way Only

Tags: linux, stow

So I have an install script that I use to stow to symlink my dotfiles and today I am noticing that in my dotfiles config directory I am seeing all the folders that actually in `$HOME/.config` directory. Maybe something has changed as I do not remember this happening before. Here is an excerpt from the shell script:

```
DOTFILES="$(pwd)"

/usr/bin/stow --stow --ignore ".DS_Store" --target="$HOME" --dir="$DOTFILES" files
```

On my Mac I do not see this problem, it seems to only be my linux machine. Thoughts?

Comment: What is `/usr/bin/stow`? I don't have it on my Mac.

Comment: `DOTFILES="$(pwd)"` that depends on the directory you run the script, not on where the script is located.

Comment: @Barmar that is the directory that stow is installed in on my arch system. @JuanR this is ran from `%HOME/.dotfiles` directory

Comment: I hadn't heard of `stow` before, I had to google it. It's not a standard program.